# jquery file uploader plugin not upload automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

I am attempting to implement a image uploader to my website.

I am using spring boot+jquery file uploader

Following the instruction, my code is setup as:

```
        <!--file uploader-->
        <div>
            <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="images" data-url="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"+'/file/upload'" multiple>

                <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/jQuery-File-Upload-9.17.0/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
                <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/jQuery-File-Upload-9.17.0/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
                <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/jQuery-File-Upload-9.17.0/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
                <script>
                $(function () {
                    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                        autoUpload: true,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        done: function (e, data) {
                        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
                        });
                    },
                    progressall: function (e, data) {
                        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                        $('#progress .bar').css(
                            'width',
                            progress + '%'
                        );
                    }
                    });
                });
                $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data){
                    console.log("fileuploadadd");
                });
                $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadstart', function (e, data){
                    console.log("fileuploadstart");
                });
            </script>
        </div>
        <div id="progress">
            <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;  background: green; height: 18px;"></div>
        </div>
```

Then I try to click choose files, there is no response and nothing happens. Expectedly my controller should receive the json data

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/file")
public class FileController extends BaseController {
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Message upload(MultipartFile[] images){

        System.out.println("recieved");

        //...image uploading

        return successMessage();
    }
}
```

So what's wrong with my code. Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe move "fileuploadadd" and "fileuploadstart" into the `$(function () {`??

Comment: @Rick Hi, I've tried that but it returns the same result. I bind these functions to catch any process if I can, but there is no console log :(